# AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'success'

Tags: python

I have a simple script using requests to validate a list of emails. Relevant code:

```
def ___process_email(email, output_file=None):   
    profile = request(email)
    if profile and profile.success != 'nothing_useful':
        logger.info('Found match for {0}'.format(email))
        print(profile)
        if output_file:
           output_file.write(str(profile) + '\n')
    else:
        print("No information found\n")
```

This ran through 5 loops successfully then threw:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 147, in <module> main()
  File "app.py", line 141, in main ___process_email(arg, output)
  File "app.py", line 107, in ___process_email if profile and profile.success != 'nothing_useful':
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'success'
```

Here's the model:

```
class Profile(object):
    def __init__(self, person):
        if person:
            self.name = person.get('name')
            self.jobinfo = [
                (occupation.get('job_title'), occupation.get('company'))
                for occupation in person.get('occupations', [])
            ]

            self.memberships = [
                (membership.get('site_name'), membership.get('profile_url'))
                for membership in person.get('memberships', [])
            ]
            self.success = person.get('success')

    def __str__(self):
        return dedent("""
            Name: {0}
            {1}
            {2}
        """).format(
            self.name,
            "\n".join(
                "{0} {1}".format(title, company)
                for title, company in self.jobinfo),
            "\n".join(
                "\t{0} {1}".format(site_name, url)
                for site_name, url in self.memberships)
        )
```

Request:

```
import requests  

def request(email):

    status_url = STATUS_URL.format(email)
    response = requests.get(status_url).json()
    session_token = response.get('session_token')
    # fail gracefully if there is an error
    if 'error' in response:
        return response['error']
    elif response['status'] == 200 and session_token:
        logger.debug('Session token: {0}'.format(session_token))
        url = URL.format(email)
        headers = {'X-Session-Token': session_token}
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
        if response.get('success') != 'nothing_useful':
           return Profile(response.get('contact'))
    return {}
```

Anyone see why my strings are unicode? thanks

Comment: And what is `request` here?

Comment: thanks updated to show request

Comment: Is the `email` to be passed to a backend service as a URL parameter? Perhaps you should leave adding GET parameters to the `requests.get()` function in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is an error in the response, you return the error string:

```
if 'error' in response:
    return response['error']
```

That's your `unicode` value there. Note that the same function returns either the `'error'` value, a new `Profile()` instance, or an empty dictionary. You may want to make this more consistent, return only `Profile()` istances and `None` instead.

Instead of the error string, raise an exception and handle the exception in your `___process_email` method:

```
class EmailValidationError(Exception):
    pass
```

and in your `request()` function:

```
if 'error' in response:
    raise EmailValidationError(response['error'])
```

then handle this in `__process_email()` with something like:

```
try:
    profile = request(email)
    if profile and profile.success != 'nothing_useful':
        logger.info('Found match for {0}'.format(email))
        print(profile)
        if output_file:
           output_file.write(str(profile) + '\n')
    else:
        print("No information found\n")
except EmailValidationError:
    # Do something here
```